# How can I launch a C++ native application from a Windows Service main function (the application interacts with the console)?

Tags: c++, windows-services

I'm using the `_spawnl()` function for launching a C++ native application from the main Service function (`SvcMain`), but the application never gets to run.

Is there any trick to launch applications that interacts with the user?

Answer (score 0):

It runs, you just cannot see it.  You have to use [`CreateProcessAsUser()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx) instead of `_spawnl()` so the new process runs in a specific user's session, not in the service's own session.  In Vista and later, services run in their own isolated sessions (Session 0 Isolation), which users cannot see or interact with.  A common solution is to use [`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383835.aspx) and/or [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) to find the desired user session, then use [`WTSQueryUserToken()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383840.aspx) to get a token hanlde can be used with [`CreateEnvironmentBlock()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762270.aspx) and `CreateProcessAsUser()`.  Also, when providing a `STARTUPINFO` to `CreateProcessAsUser()`, set the `lpDesktop` field to `"WinSta0\\default"` (the user's default desktop that they can interact with after logging in).

Comment: Thanks. If I just want to launch the application (this application needs to be launched as out of the service process), and I do NOT want the service to interacts with the application that will be launched. Will the above suggestions still apply for my case?

Comment: Yes.  You said you want the **user** to interact with the app, so you have to run it in the user's session, and `CreateProcessAsUser()` can do that.

Comment: I cannot see the my application running on the desktop. Please take a look at my code.

Comment: I could not paste the code (too big). The CreateProcessAsUser() function succeeded, but the application is not running in the desktop.

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32101457/edit) to show the code. Do not try to post it in a comment here.  You are likely using `CreateProcessAsUser()` incorrectly.  I know it works, I use it in my own services to launch interactive processes.